# Updating many attributes at once in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I need to update a dozen of attributes to x for all features that have a value of y in an other attribute.

Is there a way to update more than one attribute at once in field calculator?

Comment: Try modelbuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Field Calculator will only update one field at a time when run through its tool dialog.

To update multiple fields you could create a tool in ModelBuilder or ArcPy that runs the Calculate Field tool once for each field.

Alternatively, using an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor() would be the way that I would choose to do it.

Comment: To add to this, you can also right-click the Calculate Field Tool in the Toolbox and run it as a batch process.